# Process Update on multiple dimensions daily

Tags: process, ssas, dimension

I have a cube which needs to be updated daily. There are multiple dimensions which are used by a measure group with daily increment data

By my understanding, when "Process update" a dimension, the dependent measure group will be automatically updated if there is any attribute relationship change in the dimension.

But if I do "Process update" all dimensions sequentially, will the dependent measure group by updated multiple times? Or is there a way to suppress the dependent measure group update till all dimensions are processed?

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 0):

"Process Update" of a dimension does not process the measure group itself. What it does - as far as I understand it - with regard to measure groups is: detecting changes in attributes for existing keys in the dimension, and adapting the direct indexes between the measure group and the attributes. I. e. if the product with key 12345 was in product group A yesterday, and the process update finds that today the record with this dimension key belongs to product group B, then the index from the measure group to the product group is corrected for existing measure group records for product key 12345 to point to product group B now.

And this is something that needs to be done per dimension, actually per dimension attribute. You cannot save anything by postponing this to a common process.